# c# Entity model with multiple option of primary/foreign key

Tags: c#, model, foreign-keys

Currently I have an entity model which looks like this

```
public class Statistics : Entity
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Student")]
    public override string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

It was only build for `Student` class, now I wish to edit the model to allow another entity to use as well, for example `Teacher` class.

Therefore what I did is i separate it into 2 model, `StatisticsStudent` and `StatisticsTeacher`. Each for every classes.

**Question, is that possible to make it into 1 model?**

For example, alternative it using same `Id` column but link to different entity.

And also I prefer the *primary and foreign key as a same column instead of using another foreign key column such as* `TeacherId` and `StudentId`

```
public class Statistics : Entity
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Student"), ForeignKey("Teacher")]
    public override string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Any advice to this will be appreciated. Thanks.